# Discord JS, how to fetch a guild member if I have his discord user

Tags: javascript, discord

I have to rename everyone on my pretty big guild back to their normal names

I have a message on which most of them set their reaction and I go through all of the reactions getting the user - author of each,
Can I somehow get the member of each person by knowing their discord user?
I restart my bot often and it doesnt have anyone cached

Code:

```
var getReactedUsers = async (msg, channelID, messageID, emoji) => {
  let cacheChannel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID);
  if (cacheChannel) {
    cacheChannel.messages.fetch(messageID).then((reactionMessage) => {
      reactionMessage.reactions
        .resolve(emoji)
        .users.fetch()
        .then((userList) => {
          return userList.map((user) => {
            // Need to get guild.member here
          });
        });
    });
  }
};

getReactedUsers(msg, "664102059909313659", "665666621622082866", "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Welcome to Stack Overflow! Hope you find the answers you need here!**

The method that will solve your problem is [.fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch), in the documentation you can find further information about it, if you want to do further changes. Basically, as you map the user list, you will only need to do this to fetch the member:

```
let cacheChannel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID); 

if (cacheChannel) {
    cacheChannel.messages.fetch(userID).then(reactionMessage => {
        reactionMessage.reactions.resolve(emoji).users.fetch().then(userList => {
            return userList.map((user) => {
                msg.guild.members.fetch(user.id).then(() => {
                    // console.log(msg.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)) <- Your code here basically
                });
            })
        });
    });
}
```

After some testing, I wrote that code. In a nutshell, now that you fetched the user through its ID, you can get the user from the cache as a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), as show in the `console.log`.